# How to print a message inside a dynamically created table - PHP

Tags: php

Hi How do correct the following code? I believe something is missing in the code. 
Hope you get what I'm trying to do.

Thanks,

```
echo "<td>if(!empty($tip1)) echo $tip1;</td>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo "<td>" . (!empty($tip1) ? $tip1 : "") . "</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<td>".(!empty($tip1) ? $tip1 : "")."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(!empty($tip))
echo "<td>$tip</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 echo "<td>" .(!empty($tip1) ? $tip1 : ""). "</td>";
```

You mixed up concatenating strings and php code.